# What affects the wear rate of clothing items?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Do we know anything about differential wear rates between clothing items?

1. Does material affect wear rate?  (Leather, cloth, silk, yarn, adamantine; do they wear out at different speeds?)
2. Does quality affect wear rate?  (Does a masterwork item last longer than an ordinary one?)
3. Do different clothing types wear at different rates?
4. Does decoration have any effect on wear?

Comment: I was about to link to the DF Wiki article on [wear](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=DF2012:Wear), but I see that you've [already found it](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=DF2012:Wear&diff=170247&oldid=169592). :) Given how sparse the page is, I think this is an area that could do with more research.

Comment: You might try looking through the raws and seeing what you find. I'd do it myself, but I don't actually have the latest version. I'm waiting for this next update.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Good thought, but the raws are unenlightening, to me at least.  There's nothing that seems to directly speak to wear in the material or item files.  And I wouldn't really expect it to; Toady being Toady, I'd look for any differential wear being determined on a more abstract level.

Comment: Im fairly sure that no material affects wear rates, but that's based on a discussion ages ago on the bay12 forum.

And boots wear faster

Comment: Yeah, even adamantine undies wear out :/

Answer (score 2):

I've been playing DF for probably five years now. I'll tell you what I know.

1. From my experence (I may be wrong), adamantine definitely seems to last longer then leather but it does happen.
2. I don't think quality affects wear rate.
3. No.
4. Yes, Mr Asmel Oceanworked can love cat bones. So if you give him a shirt with cat bones I think he goes head over heels with joy.

Comment: I would note that although ordinary quality levels (through masterwork) don't seem to affect wear rate, artifacts are completely immune to wear. Not that this is really helpful, but it's true.